# defuse.ca online GAS assembler accepts AT&T syntax for movb and movw, but not movl?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I'm using https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly to assemble x86 instructions to machine code.  (Editor's note: it uses GAS in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode.)

---

The below code throws `` Error: no such instruction: `movl $0xdeadbeef,0x08048c5f' ``

```
movl $0xdeadbeef,0x08048c5f
```

But the following assembly code works fine

```
movb $0xdeadbeef, 0x08048c5f
movw $0xdeadbeef, 0x08048c5f
```

Comment: You are not getting that error when you *execute* the code; you may be getting that error when you try to assemble/compile that code. Show more of your source.

Comment: Sounds like you might be using the wrong assembler/compiler. Provide more information.

Comment: The x86 has different instructions for moving bytes, double-bytes, quad-bytes, and 8-bytes.  YOu have to tell the assembler *something* so it knows what size target and thus which instruction to choose.  "movb" for your particular assembler appears to indicate "move byte", likewise for "movw".  "mov" apparantly means nothing to your particular assembler.  READ THE ASSEMBLER MANUAL BEFORE ASKING ANY MORE QUESTIONS ON THIS SPECIFIC SUBJECT.

Comment: Read your assembler manual?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using AT&T syntax for your movl, but the page you link states that it wants Intel syntax.

If I understand your intention correctly, the correct syntax for the instruction you want would be;

```
MOV DWORD PTR ds:0x08048c5f, 0xdeadbeef
```

(which stores the double word value 0xdeadbeef at address 0x08048c5f)

Comment: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly is very strange.  It accepts AT&T syntax for `movb` and `movw`, but not `movl`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm that's weird like this: it just uses GAS in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode.

(So you want `mov dword ptr [0x08048c5f], 0xdeadbeef` as @Joachim says)

---

**But the interesting part here is that the GNU assembler accepts `movb` and `movw`, but not `movl`, when in Intel-syntax mode!!**

However, it's *not* interpreting them as AT&T syntax.  In Intel-syntax, the destination is on the left, and **`$0xdeadbeef` is a valid symbol name** because it starts with a `$`, not a digit.  GAS's `.intel_syntax` mode is MASM-like, where (like AT&T syntax) a bare symbol name is a memory operand.

The surprising thing is that `movb` is accepted as specifying byte operand-size for `mov`, but once we get past that, **`movb $0xdeadbeef, 0x08048c5f` is equivalent to `mov byte ptr [label], 0x5f`**.

Note that the `0x08048c5f` constant (which you intended to be the destination address) is the immediate source operand.  And it's truncated to 8 bits.  GAS warns about this, but the online assembler hides the warnings that would have helped you figure out this weirdness. :(

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

movb $0xdeadbeef, 0x08048c5f
movw $0xdeadbeef, 0x08048c5f
```

On my Linux desktop with `as --version` = GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1

```
$ as -32 syntax.s -o syntax.o
as -32 -o syntax.o syntax.s 
syntax.s: Assembler messages:
syntax.s:3: Warning: 134515807 shortened to 95
syntax.s:4: Warning: 134515807 shortened to 35935

$ objdump -drwC -Matt syntax.o 

syntax.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   c6 05 00 00 00 00 5f    movb   $0x5f,0x0        2: R_386_32     $0xdeadbeef
   7:   66 c7 05 00 00 00 00 5f 8c      movw   $0x8c5f,0x0      a: R_386_32     $0xdeadbeef

$ ld -melf_i386 syntax.o 
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000
ld: syntax.o:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `$0xdeadbeef'
ld: syntax.o:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `$0xdeadbeef'
```

Trying to link, and asking `objdump` to show relocations with `-r` in the `.o`, make it clear that that `$0xdeadbeef` is being treated as a symbol name, no different than if I'd used `my_label` instead.

With just the online assembler, it would be a lot harder to figure this out because it only shows you the machine code.  The `00 00 00 00` for the destination address is your only clue that something weird happened.

---

**I have no idea why movb and movw are accepted, but movl doesn't imply dword operand-size.**

It's probably a GAS bug that they're accepted at all.